# Efeito de transparência nos componentes

Tags: android

Como utilizar o efeito de transparência em meus componentes como por exemplo em um botão ou um textview?

Comment: poderia colocar a imagem de um botão com e sem esse efeito na pergunta?

Comment: `android:alpha="1"` 1 = 100%

Comment: Era isso aí mesmo valeu luc

Answer (score 0):

tente adicionar esse atributo no seu botão

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```